# Method 'add_PropertyChanged' in type '.." from assembly "..."does not have an implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-mvc-2, dataset

Im working on a MVC projcet and traying to retrieve data from database.
this problem i get when i run the applikation

> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Method
>   'add_PropertyChanged' in type '~BI.Production.ProductionOrderItem'
>   from assembly '~.BI.Production, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

no problem i get when i test it on ASP project, got the problem only on MVC

here my controller

```
  public class ProdukterController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString.ToString());

     ProductionOrderList produkter = ProductionOrderReg.GetProductionOrders(conn, new Guid("28937bcc-6eaf-4b5a-a789-fadff99403cd"));

    ViewData["produkter"] = produkter;
        return View();
    }
```

here my view, Gridview

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = ViewData["produkter"];
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Search for that exact name , then decide if you need that event. The error is not in this code but somewhere in your DataSet

Comment: but it works when i test it on asp c# projekt and it retrieve data.

Comment: There may be an handler or override in the asp project that you didn't copy. Search for that name in both projects.

Comment: there is nothing called 'add_PropertyChanged in the project

Comment: Well, than I give up. Datasets aren't used much with MVC